# How to have the parent div of an svg display its shadow on top of that svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm making an iteractive map with an svg map of the world. It has to be SVG because I have setup a way to zoom in and move the map around. Here is the problem : The SVG covers up the parent div's shadow.

Here is the CSS and HTML code:

```css
.map__image{
 width: 58%;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: -6px -6px 14px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7),
             -6px -6px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5),
             6px 6px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, .075),
             6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
 margin:14px;
 padding:0.8rem;
                
}

.map__image svg path{
 fill: #035796;
 stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
 stroke-width: 1px;
 transition: fill 0.3s;
}

.map__image .is-active path{
 fill:#4e87b3;
}

.svg {
 z-index: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 transition: ease-in 300ms;
 border:none;
 user-select:none;
 display: block;
 opacity: 0.9;
                 
}

#pagecarte{        
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7),
             inset -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5),
             inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .075),
             inset 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
                
}
            
#reset{
 background: #efefef;
 border: none;
 border-radius: .5rem;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
 color: #444;
 font-size: 1rem;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: .1rem;
 font-family: Raleway;
 text-align: center;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 user-select:none;
 transition: .2s ease-in-out;
 box-shadow: -6px -6px 14px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7),
             -6px -6px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5),
              6px 6px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, .075),
              6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
 padding:.8rem 1.2rem;
 margin:0.8rem;
                
}

#reset:hover {
 box-shadow: -2px -2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, .6),
             -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4),
              2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .05),
              2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#reset:active {
 box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7),
             inset -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5),
             inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .075),
             inset 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test Carte Du Monde</title>
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" class="map">
            <div class="map__image">
                <div id="pagecarte">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:amcharts="http://amcharts.com/ammap" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1051 678" id="svg">
                        
                        <g id="shape">
                            <a id="region-AE" xlink:title="United Arab Emirates" > 
                                    <path class="land" d="M619.874,393.722L620.373,393.573L620.477,394.411L622.671,393.93L624.99,394.009L626.684,394.1L628.604,392.028L630.695,390.054L632.467,388.146L633.001,389.202L633.382,391.639L631.949,391.651L631.72,393.648L632.216,394.073L630.947,394.674L630.939,395.919L630.122,397.175L630.049,398.394L629.484,399.032L621.056,397.508L619.981,394.428z"/>
                            </a>
                            
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                
                <button id="reset" , class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect controls-button">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*1-I have a javascript file that takes care of the "is-active" class and the SVG scaling and panning.*

*2-I have a lot more paths in the SVG section but for the sakes of this example, I only put one in*

Answer (score 0):

We need to place the shadow above the SVG then, cleanest solution is using a pseudo element, add this to your CSS

```
#pagecarte::before {
  content: "";
  z-index: 1; /* make sure it's above SVG */
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  pointer-events: none; /* so it does not interfere with panning */
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 6px rgb(255 255 255 / 70%), inset -2px -2px 4px rgb(255 255 255 / 50%), inset 2px 2px 2px rgb(255 255 255 / 8%), inset 2px 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 15%)
}
```